# Socket.IO start a connection from client to a third-party server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, client

I am using socket.io on the client and I want to start a connection from the client to a server that runs node with socket.io installed.

Is this possible? 
Cat I do this using socket.io-client?

This is my code

**CLIENT**

`<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.5/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script>
    var socket = io.connect("localhost:8001")
</script>`

In the browser console I get the following error

GET http://file/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LF7pj8U **net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

**SERVER**

```
var http = require("http")
var io = require('socket.io')
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
})
server.listen(8001)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the socket.io server is not the same node instance than the http server you'll need to instanciate socket service like this :

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.listen(8001);
```

Comment: Thank you. I've changed the server file with yours. I've also moved my client file on apache server and accessed it on localhost and now works fine.